# How to use a Django GenericRelation in a values_list query

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have those two models in my Django app:

```
class ItemOrigin(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()
    [...]

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    origins = generic.GenericRelation(ItemOrigin)
    [...]
```

In Django 1.4, the following query used to work:

```
ItemOrigin.objects.values_list('id', 'place')
```

But since upgrading to Django 1.6, that query generates the following error message:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'place' into field. Choices are: content_type, created, dubitable, evidence, historical_item, id, legacy_id, modified, object_id
```

I may have missed something in the upgrade notes but I cannot see any mention of a compatibility break related to this kind of queries.

So my questions are: why isn't it working any more and, more importantly, how can I fix it so the same query will work. I'd prefer a solution where the query code is not modified (much) as it's much harder to change than the model definitions in my app. This is because my querying system in dynamic and the list of fields passed in values_list is derived from a config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That worked in Django < 1.6 but was untested and undocumented. There is a [open ticket here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21559).

For a workaround, you can do this:

```
ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Place)
pk_list = ItemOrigin.objects.filter(
    content_type=ctype
).values_list('object_id', flat=True)
places = Place.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the ticket and the alternative query. I knew I could query it like that but was hoping there was was a way to avoid it and keep using single query that can be easily parametrised. To complicate matters I also forced the joins to OUTER LEFT on my original query (i.e. including ItemOrigins without the place or pointing to other tables) so the new version forced by the Django 1.6 is quite disappointing.

Comment: Unless they're going to change that in version 1.7, I don't think you have any alternative. Besides, it worked by accident, so you might want to use the double queries anyway.

Comment: For the record I decided to convert the GenericForeignKey into multiple ForeignKey fields as it allows me to keep my dynamic querying system intact instead of having to juggle with separate queries.